# Unable to find package:flutter_driver in D:\DevFlutter\flutter\packages\flutter_driver

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter so whenever I try create app with command: `flutter create`

`Unable to find package:flutter_driver in D:\DevFlutter\flutter\packages\flutter_driver`

this is the error I usually get, what shall i do??

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall flutter sdk and try again.

Comment: how Can I reinstall Flutter SDK? your means is that download the zip file and re-extract?

Comment: Yes! you can do that.

Comment: The zipe file in flutter website is not sufficient for running a flutter project, I downloaded it more then one time, but combining the downloaded file and a new one rescue me from this challenge.

Comment: you should delete "flutter" SDK folder completely and extract the zip file or you can extract and replace. Try it and aware me.

Comment: surely, I imitate this way more than once, but, as I said it doesn't work for me. The size of Flutter SDK in the flutter website approximately is 138M, which is far from what I have in my PC.

Comment: Ok. then try terminal command line for installing flutter sdk.